# Error when using one JS file for multiple HTML files

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a rock, paper, scissors game with HTML, CSS, and JS. I have a homepage (allows user to select how many rounds and enter usernames for themself and the CPU) and a game page that actually plays the game. This means that I have two HTML pages, one called `index.html` and another called `game.html`. When I click play, the JS file stores the number of rounds and the usernames. There are no errors on the homepage. However, as soon as I go to the game page, an error occurs, saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is the JS code:

```
// Sets number of wins and rounds
let wins = undefined;
let rounds = document.querySelectorAll(".rounds");
    rounds.forEach(i => {
        i.addEventListener("click", () => {
            rounds.forEach(j => j.style.cssText = "color: white; border-color: white");
            i.style.cssText = "color: gray; border-color: gray";
            wins = Math.round((i.textContent.slice(-1)) / 2);
        });
    });

// Starts game
let play = document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Stores player and CPU names
    let playerName = document.getElementById("player-name").value;
    let cpuName = document.getElementById("cpu-name").value;
    if (playerName === "") {
        playerName = "You";
    }
    if (cpuName === "") {
        cpuName = "CPU";
    }
    window.location.replace("/game/game.html");
});
```

Here is the `index.HTML` code

```
    <div id="rounds">
        <button class="rounds">Best of 1</button>
        <button class="rounds">Best of 3</button>
        <button class="rounds">Best of 5</button>
    </div>
    <div id="names">
        <input id="player-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter Your Name'>
        <input id="cpu-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter CPU Name'>
    </div>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
```

The `game.HTMl` file is just some filler text.

Comment: The error means `document.getElementById("play")` returned `null`. Which in turn means that no such element with the ID "play" existed in that page when the code was executed. Without any other info about your page or how it works, that's as much information as we can tell you right now. Presumably you need to check whether you've used the correct ID, and/or whether that element has been created before you execute this code.

Comment: P.S. all this setting of variables e.g. `playerName = ...`, `cpuName  = ...`  etc is completely futile, if you're going to immediately change to another page just afterwards. Do you understand that web pages are both stateless and completely self-contained? So any Javascript variables you declare in one page are not accessible from another page. In fact as soon as you leave the "index.html" page, they will be destroyed, because the page is removed from the browser's memory - they won't even be initialised next time you come back to that same page, because it loads a fresh copy.

Comment: @ADyson Could I just make another JS file and then export these variables?

Comment: To be honest unless you have another specific reason for separating them, it would probably be simpler to just implement everything inside a single page.

Comment: Ok I'll add more HTML. in the question to make it clearer

Comment: Sure. But...have you got a specific reason for having separate pages? There's a good chance it's completely unnecessary to begin with.

Comment: One HTML page is the homepage while another is for the actual game.

Comment: Ok. But that could all be done in one page, using hidden sections. That's very common these days - have you heard of the phrase "single-page application" or "SPA"?

Comment: Oh ok. So I'll have everything for one page in a div, then everything in another for the second page. I'll use display: none for the game page, then as soon as I leave the homepage, I reverse it?

Comment: why a loop in a loop? `rounds.forEach(j` inside `    `rounds.forEach(i => {` seems like you need to know about `this` inside there

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's so I can only allow one button at a time to be shaded.

Comment: @JoshuaLiu yes two divs would be the simplest way to achieve it. The advantage of this is that all your JS variables persist the whole time. P.S. if you're just getting started with Javascript and web page development, once you've got the basics you should consider looking into frameworks such as React or Vue which make developing this kind of app a much more structured process, and generally make it easier to develop more complex UIs.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the help! I just wanted to make a vanilla JS game to make sure I have the fundamentals before moving on.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Is there a better way to do it with `this`?

Comment: @JoshuaLiu absolutely that's a sensible way to do it. Those frameworks can be overwhelming if you try to use them immediately with no previous JS or HTML experience. They generally assume prior knowledge of key concepts.

Answer (score 1):

This might look slightly more complicated but it

- Namespaces all our objects
- Allows us to use the "this" in those to reference our object
- has a single function call to instantiate it
- Avoids any global objects except our namespace
- Uses classes which is better, allows us to set some better CSS without replacing it each time
- Toggles the classes so we get CSS we can manipulate outside the logic (change the background color, etc.

```js
/namespace all our stuff to avoid globals
var myApp = {
  wins: 0,
  playerName: "Wilber",
  player: {},
  cpu: {},
  cpuName: "CPU",
  // so we can use .filter directly
  allRounds: [...document.querySelectorAll('.rounds')],
  playButton: document.getElementById("play"),
  message: document.getElementById("message"),
  onRoundClick: function(el, index) {
    //otherElements not really used but we could
    // toggle classes with logic/what it is
    let otherElements = this.allRounds
      .filter(function(element) {
        let isMe = element === el;
        element.classList.toggle("notme", !isMe);
        element.classList.toggle("mec", isMe);
        return !isMe;
      });
  },
  start: function() {
    // Stores player and CPU names
    this.player = document.getElementById("player-name");
    this.playerName = this.player.value === "" ? "You" : this.player.value;
    this.cpu = document.getElementById("cpu-name");
    this.cpuName = this.cpu.value === "" ? "CPU" : this.cpu.value;
    this.message.innerHTML = "Playing " + this.playerName + " vs " + this.cpuName;
    this.allRounds
      .forEach((el, index) => {
        // bind "this" to the function and pass other parameters, this == myApp
        el.addEventListener('click', this.onRoundClick.bind(this, el, index));
      });
  }
};

myApp.playButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // this is the window object, inside start "this" will be myApp
  this.myApp.start();
});;
```

```css
.notme {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: lightblue;
}

.mec {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<div id="rounds">
  <button class="rounds">Best of 1</button>
  <button class="rounds">Best of 3</button>
  <button class="rounds">Best of 5</button>
</div>
<div class="players">
  <input id="player-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter Your Name'>
  <input id="cpu-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter CPU Name'>
</div>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<div id="message"></div>
```